# Is it possible to use RenderScript through the NDK with the Gnu STL?

Tags: android-ndk, renderscript

I am trying to integrate RenderScript into my company's C++ app. However, I get an error when trying to include `libRScpp_static.a`

```
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:158: error: undefined reference to 'std::__node_alloc::_M_allocate(unsigned int&)'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:161: error: undefined reference to 'std::__node_alloc::_M_deallocate(void*, unsigned int)'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_string.c:600: error: undefined reference to 'std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_vector.c:41: error: undefined reference to 'std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:158: error: undefined reference to 'std::__node_alloc::_M_allocate(unsigned int&)'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_string.c:600: error: undefined reference to 'std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
```

Since our app uses the Gnu STL while `libRScpp_static.a` is 
[compiled against STLport](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/cpp/Android.mk),
I assume this is because of binary incompatibility between those STL implementations.

How can I use RenderScript with the Gnu STL?

**NB:** Switching to STLport is impossible.

**UPDATE:** Linking against the dynamic library (`libRScpp.so`) instead seems to solve the problem. I'm not sure why and we would prefer to link statically if possible.

**UPDATE:** `libRScpp.so` has been removed in NDK r9d. I have resorted to compiling a shared library of my own, which links statically with `STLport` and exposes no STL/RenderScript symbols.